# How to use a function inside string?

Tags: php, string

```
'<a rel="nofollow" href="$1" class="bbc_link new_win" target="_blank">'
```

I would like use the `urlencode()` function:

```
 '<a rel="nofollow" href="urlencode($1)" class="bbc_link new_win" target="_blank">'
```

... but I can't use this:

```
 '<a rel="nofollow" href="'.urlencode($1).'" class="bbc_link new_win" target="_blank">'
```

... because `$1` is not a variable in the string; it is instead a meta-variable in a simple free forum.

it send `http://www.test.com/out.php?out=http://www.example.com`

Answer (score 6):

how about this crazy hack?

```
<?
$_ = 'urlencode';
echo "<a rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"{$_($1)}\" class=\"bbc_link new_win\" target=\"_blank\">";
```

Answer (score 5):

Check out this trick:

```
function foo() { return "title"; }

$func = function($param) { return $param; };

$link = 'http://www.test.com/out.php?out=http://www.example.com';
echo "<a rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"{$func(urlencode($link))}\" class=\"bbc_link new_win\" target=\"_blank\">{$func(foo())}</a>";
```

`$func()` will be called as a function, and the expression in the parentheses will be evaluated as any other PHP code.

[hack is found here](http://blog.nazdrave.net/?p=626)

Comment: Nice one, however the link is dead. It would be nice to see a workable reference to this trick. That said, it does appear to work; this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

There is a way to do this, but take my advice and do not use it. you should not use function calls inside strings.
However I´ll post an example just to show what PHP is capable of.

**BUT THIS IS AN EXTREME SAMPLE OF BAD PROGRAMMING!!!!**

```
<?php
class FunctionAgent{
    public function __call($name,$args){
        switch (count($args)){
            case 0:
                return  $name();
                break;
            case 1:
                return  $name($args[0]);
                break;
            case 2:
                return  $name($args[0],$args[1]);
                break;  
            case 3:
                return  $name($args[0],$args[1],$args[2]);
                break;
            case 4:
                return  $name($args[0],$args[1],$args[2],$args[3]);
                break;
            case 5:
                return  $name($args[0],$args[1],$args[2],$args[3],$args[4]);
                break;
        }
    }   
}

$_ = new  FunctionAgent();
echo "the current date is {$_->date("y-m-d")}";

?>
```

Comment: Your warning echoes my intuition. But the only problem with this I can actually explicate is that it's unfamiliar convention.  Classes/objects are indeed [bad practice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poltergeist_(computer_science)) -- _in an OOP context_.  If `FunctionAgent` makes a dev's life easier (and every millisecond of script execution time isn't a concern), why not use it?

Comment: @smhmic My golden rule is: stick to what people expect or document it verbosly. It is very interesting how rare you brake the "rules" if you have to write a in depth explanation what you are doing, why you ae doing it and which "cleaner" approaches youconsidered and dismissed. But looking at this 3 year old code I realize I should use `call_user_func`

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this. You need to encode the value where it's generated or where it's replaced in this string, not in this template where you don't have access to it.

Answer (score 2):

I've just reviewed the [string parsing section of the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing) and there doesn't appear to be a way of calling a function from within a quoted string (except for dynamically assigning a variable name). Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend how your templating engine works in order to support this. There's no way to make PHP do it for you.