# Using functions in {$variable brackets} PHP

Tags: php, syntax, echo

Basically in php I use special multilanguage way of printing my page. And I would like to use a function in brackets. Something like that: {$functon(variable)}, but It gives an error

Sample code:

```
$pageContents = <<< EOPAGE

<!doctype html>

<html lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>{$langues[$langue]['title']}</title>
</head>

<body>
    <section class="page-container">
        <header>
            <h1>{$langues[$langue]['header']}</h1>
            <p>{$langues[$langue]['about']}</p>
        </header>
        <section>
            <article> 
                {$article(1)} // here I would like to parse function but it gives me an error
            </article>
        </section>

    </section>
</body>
</html>
EOPAGE;

echo $pageContents;
```

Comment: And what's the error message now? What does `$article` contain?

Comment: it outputs article (text) by id from mysql table

Comment: Are you sure that you have `$article` variable?

Comment: Look , I wanna use function which returns string in {brackets} not variable

Comment: So, you have `article` function?

Comment: you can't. you would have to break out ofthe heredoc to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [anonymous function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) like this:

```
$article = function( $item ) { return $item; };

$pageContents = 
<<< EOPAGE
    <article> 
        {$article(1)}
    </article>
EOPAGE;

echo $pageContents;
```

Also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447234/how-to-use-a-function-inside-string/16590903#16590903) is a similar answer.

Comment: Thank you! That worked with using $aricle = function( $item ) { return article($item); };

Comment: @CableErector You obviously won't realize, but an anonymous function to wrap a named function is pointless. You could just use the function name literal for a variable expression function call.